# how to Connect or SSH real android device from local Macbook to Remote Centos7 vm server

Tags: android, docker, ssh, appium, adb

I'm getting a problem with connecting the android device(ADB) to VM(CENTOS7) running on a server, that VM is our development machine but the devices are plugged in on our local machine... is there a way that I can plug my devices locally and give access to connect remote VM?
this is the schema [server (VM)]----[lan]-----[localmachine (pixel phone)]
I read something about using ADB connect but it's not working... don't know if I'm doing it wrong.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Docker machine setup over the centOS server. You can use this command.

```
docker run --privileged -d -p 4723:4723  -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb --name container-appium appium/appium
```

or you can go to VM setting to enable android device in the USB settings of the VM.

Then simply disable the adb from your local Macbook by using

```
adb kill-server
```